# How to start as a control system engineer and to make advanced projects using PID

Tags: control, pid, books

I am new to the field of control systems, PID and robotics and I want to enhance my knowledge in the field. Can you recommend me books where I can start learning about control system engineering (with mathematical and practical examples) so I can finally finish my project. (I am working on quad copter and I can find all codes online but can't understand it because some people here told me that I should start reading on these subjects first).

Comment: `can't understand it` ... which part do you not understand .... there is no way to answer your question because we have no way of knowing how much you already know

Comment: Okay. I need to start from the begining, to learn the control theory and how it is  related to PID and then go to some practical examples @jsotola

Answer (score 2):

I can see two parts to this question!

1. You need to learn the math needed to develop such control systems in an advance manner.

   - Look for Author: *Norman S. Nice - Control Systems Engineering. Sixth Edition* I found this PDF online and was used in my course.
2. the programming skills needed to convert this math into a usable system.

**Warning** - Controlling a quadcopter is not beginner level task and requires at the least.

1. Good calibration and a Kaman filter on the accelerometer(acc) data.
2. The ability to transpose the the filtered acc data to a real world coordinate frame.
3. Power algorithm to determine the needed PWM output at a given motor to achieve flight.
4. PID control that uses the filtered acc data to determine error between set-point and actual data.
5. A good PID tune to make the system function as intended.
6. Programming skills in data manipulation and math.

Assuming you would be using Arduino or C/C++ you could simply google "quad*copter PID Arduino" and you would get 100's of matches.

Comment: Thanks. I dont want premade algos. I need to make them from scratch so I can understand them. Ok I will find the book and buy it. But how can I study the second part of the question which is controlling the quadcopter

Comment: Be a little more specific, when you say controlling the quadcopter! what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Make it stable when I stop working with RC. Gather information so it will prevent hitting walls or trees, fly with it normally without any movement perturbations.

Comment: By the way, what is your course Ben and can I find it online ?

Answer (score 2):

Making advanced projects with PID control is easy. At first, a uav-testbed is needed. This consists of two UAVs at the same time. The left UAV is controlled by the human operator with a joystick. And the right UAV is controlled by the pid-tracking controller. The idea is, that the pid-controller follows the human-demonstration in realtime and reduces the error. Such a set-up results not to the Artificial Intelligence itself, but it is only a development platform for testing out different kinds of pid-controllers. A more advanced form is model-predictive control, in which the error between the demonstration and the autonomous controlled vehicle is reduced by a dedicated model which can be a physics-engine, a transfer function or a neural network.

Finding good books about the topic is indeed a problem. I can only provide a link to paper which is not very useful [Real-Time Predictive Control of an UR5 Robotic Arm Through Human Upper Limb Motion Tracking](http://www.alaris.kz/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/lbr1899_Omarali.pdf) because it has nothing to do with UAV control. Another problematic source [Designing Interactive Blimps as Puppets](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f0d9/2c6618a29583136ff2c4193ab9c3d6d899b3.pdf) is unscientific because it is from the area of animatronics.

Comment: Thanks. It is really hard to find resources related to this field.